# Nth root in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I know that I can get the square root of a number in bash with something like this:

```
sqrt ( $aux )" | bc
```

However, can I get the Nth root of a floating point number in a bash script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the math, n-th root of the number x could be written as:

> <sup>*n*</sup>√*x* = *x*<sup>(1/*n*)</sup> = *e*<sup>(ln *x*)/*n*</sup>

Unfortunately, `bc` allows only interger exponents, so you can't use the `x^(1/n)` and therefore you need to use the second form, e.g.

```
echo "e( l(4)/5 )" | bc -l
```

is the 5th root for 4.

```
1.31950791077289425936
```

or just use perl and the `x**1/n`

```
perl -E 'say 4**(1/5)' #parentheses are needed
# 1.31950791077289
```

Comment: Nice n-th root crash course.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk` and have it read arguments from argv.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print (ARGV[1] ** (1.0 / ARGV[2])) }' 4 5
1.31951
```

This prints the 5th root of 4, for instance.

There are lots of other options here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks

Comment: Thank you so much.